# How to let EGIT recognize two Git Repositories in one Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have an Eclipse project containing two Git Repositories (each different subfolder).

How do I let EGIT recognize them as Git Repositories?

Tried with Share Project, but it only seems to work on Project level, not on a subfolder.

When trying to configure a Git Repository with Share Project, I'm getting next error message:

> Cannot move project Glims_9_5_pro to target location
>   C:\Workspace\EclipseWorkspaceOE_11_3_GIT\Glims_9_5_pro\smartcomponents\Glims_9_5_pro,
>   as this location overlaps with location
>   C:\Workspace\EclipseWorkspaceOE_11_3_GIT

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could share and declare your project as a git Repo, and then add the two subrepos as submodules.

See "[Working with Submodules](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Working_with_Submodules)".

[image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/7/70/Egit-13-submodules-node.png]

That way, those submodules would be recognized as Git repo in your one Eclipse project.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Although my project isn't a Git repo (but I'll make it one).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work very easily... My project is already set up with those subfolders. Made my project a Git Repo, but now marking these subfolders as submodules doesn't seem to be easy...

Comment: @LievenCardoen sure: I would start from scratch, with a project without those subfolders. Then I would add submodules (https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Adding_a_Submodule: which would create those subfolders naturally)

Comment: Indeed, but we just created a script setting up those projects... So, like 30 developers have already set up their projects... I will have to find another way. We're currently using SourceTree, but having an Eclipse plugin would be very nice...